# Get bits per pixel of a BufferedImage

Tags: java, rgb, pixel, bufferedimage, covariance

I'm currently working on comparing a filtered image to its original (unfiltered) image using the SSIM (Structural similarity) index using Java.

My research brought me to a mathematical formula where the average, variance, covariance and the dynamic range of the two `BufferedImage`s are needed.

Getting to calculate the average and the variance was not a big problem for me, however I can't figure out a way to get the number of bits per pixel needed to calculate the dynamic range, and the covariance value, is this something I can obtain from the `BufferedImage`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BufferedImage` has a `getColorModel()` method, and in the returned `ColorModel` object there is a `getPixelSize()` method which returns the number of bits per pixel described by that `ColorModel`.

Comment: It helped me a lot!